# How do I display posts based on the users information using some sort of conditions

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In my rails app i have created a profile user system where users that would be posting have to select one city from a list of cities they are living in. in my post model i have added belongs_to :user

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { large: "300x300>", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
    belongs_to :user
    delegate :city, :to => :user
    searchkick text_start: [:title]
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :reviews
end
```

and in user model i have also added has many :posts.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: '152x152#' }
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
has_attached_file :banner, styles: { large: "500x500>", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :banner, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
    has_many :posts
    has_many :reviews
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

The problem right now is i am trying to display all the posts made by users from each city or a particular city differently on a different page corresponding to the city the post.user.city belongs.

how exactly would i query posts from users in canada for example.
in my controller i have tried:

@posts = Post.user.where("city: canada")

trust me that didn't work that because i am totally new to rails and i so much love how rails work.

i would appreciate any help or hint to tackle this problem. thanks

Comment: But `@posts = Post.user.where(city: "canada")` works?

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
@posts = Post.joins(:user).where("users.city = (?)", 'canada')
```

Comment: I got this error: NoMethodError at /pages/canada
undefined method `user' for #<Class:0xc844650>

Answer (score 0):

```
@posts = Post.joins(:user).where(users: {city: 'Canada'})
```

Comment: That gave me SystemStackError.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it worked:

Created a city model and added belongs_to :city to user model just as @Crisgm directed:

```
class City < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :posts, through: :users
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  ....
  belongs_to :city
  ....
end
```

This didn't work:

```
City.find_by(name: 'Canada').posts
```

However @Vijayakumar's idea worked on my controller:

```
@posts = Post.joins(:user).where("users.city = (?)", 'canada')
```